# How can I decode a message encrypted with a one time pad?

Tags: encryption, decrypt

I know that a one-time pad requires a non-repeating key at least equal to the length of the message to encode, but I have no idea how (or if it is even possible) to decode such a message using a one time pad. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is off-topic. With a OTP you typically decrypt the ciphertext with the same key and reverse the method that you used to encrypt the plaintext - see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad#Example)

Comment: You need to know how the one-time pad was convolved with the input source.  It may have been a simple bit-wise XOR, in which case you just XOR again.  Or it may have been something a bit more complex.

Comment: You have get more luck asking http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Do it the same way it was encrypted, but backwards.

Comment: With the most common kind of one-time-pad, you use xor to combine keystream and text which is even identical in both directions.